# Identifying a stochastic trend model

Tags: time-series, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes

My question is a bit general

Say I am given a time series $X_t$, In what ways I can use in order to check whether the sequence behaves like a stochastic trend model or not? and if yes how can I find the best fit model?

(i.e. $X_t=X_{t-1}+c+U_{t-1}$ where $U_{t}$ is some zero mean and stationary process)?

Comment: look for posts on "unit root test" or "Dickey-Fuller" on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identify an ARIMA model. If first differences are needed then include a constant/trend  in the model. If the constant is significant then you can conclude that a stochastic trend is appropriate. Other kinds of "trend models" such as a deterministic trend variable of the form X=1,2,,,,,t might be more appropriate. Testing alternatives is always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, can you recommend me a specific test?

Comment: the test statistic is the t value associated with the constant. You can obtain it in this case by simply lagging the y series 1 period and estimating a lagged regression using the lag as a predictor.